# Azure Mobile client.logout doesn't logout user in Ionic app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, azure-mobile-services

I'm using the azure-mobile-apps-client library in an Ionic app and I'm able to logon and call services just fine. However, when I call client.logout() the user isn't cleared out.

I can wait for client.logout().then(... and see that client.currentUser is now null. But the next time I call client.login() the user is logged in automatically without having to enter in a username or password. The popup browser window just says "You have successfully signed in" and a new token is returned.

Somehow, even if I log out, uninstall the app, and redeploy the user is still not asked to re-enter their password!

Does anyone know what I need to do to logout a user with the Azure mobile client?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The client.logout() merely clears the data from the local client.  The token, having been issued by a third party, is still valid.

If you want a true logout, you need to implement client-flow authentication and deal with the client provider directly, then ALSO call client.logout().

You can find the AAD client flow in my blog: https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/06/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-4-adal-integration/

Comment: Thanks, Adrian. If the client side data has been cleared though, I don't understand why the user isn't re-prompted for the user name and password. How does it know who they are?

Comment: A follow up comment after doing some research on "client-flow": I see in the docs how to use client-flow authentication by getting a token directly from a third party SDK like Facebook and passing that. But I'm only doing "aad" login with an Azure AD directory. In that situation, how would client-flow work? Aren't I already working with the client provider directly?

Comment: Same way - check out my blog "30 Days of Azure Mobile" on shellmonger.com: https://shellmonger.com/30-days-of-azure-mobile-apps-the-table-of-contents/ - I have an explicit post on login for AAD client flow with Cordova and Azure Mobile Apps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is how it's supposed to be done since the docs doesn't mention any of this. But here is what we ended up doing:

```
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(azureUrl);
client.logout().then(() => {

    var logoutUrl = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/logout";

    var options = {
        hidden: 'yes',
        clearcache: 'yes'
    };

    this.rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstop', function(e, event) {

        if (this.browser != null) {
            this.browser.close();
        }

    });

    this.browser.open(logoutUrl, '_blank', options);

}
```